# Is it possible to create jmx subdomains?

Tags: java, jmx

I'm experimenting with dynamically creating mbeans, which represent existing objects created by a framework used in my application.  These objects exist in a conceptual hierarchy, like a folder hierarchy.  If I just create the mbeans with their associated folder path, I end up with a big domain with lots of objects.

It would be very nice if my JMX viewer (presently VisualVM) could see "subfolders" of the domain associated with the folder hierarchy of these objects.

Is there some way to specify the domain or name property of the mbean so that the JMX viewer would see a hierarchy of these objects, instead of just a big flat list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there some way to specify the domain or name property of the mbean so that the JMX viewer would see a hierarchy of these objects, instead of just a big flat list?

Yes there is.  You can either specify a different domain in your `ObjectName` and/or you can specify folders as `X=Y` *before* the `name=...` portion of the name.  For example:

```
... = new ObjectName("foo.com:00=folder,01=subFolder,name=SomeBean");
```

This will create the `SomeBean` managed JMX bean.  It will show up under the `foo.com` top-level domain folder.  Inside of `foo.com` will be a folder named `folder` and within that, a sub-folder named `subFolder`.  See the below image from jconsole:

[image]

The full `ObjectName` of the bean is visible to the right.  I use the `00=folder,01=subfolder` folder names convention.  I'm not sure if the numbers are at all visible but the order is critical.  The `00` name (in this example `folder`) is the folder under the domain.  The `01` name is the folder inside of the 00 folder (in this example `subfolder`).  There is no limit to the number of sub-folders.

If you want another folder at the same level as `folder` then you would just use a different `00` name:

```
... = new ObjectName("foo.com:00=folder2,name=AnotherBean");
```

As an aside, you might want to look at my [`SimpleJMX` package](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) which does all of the JMX heavy lifting for you.  Here's the [example program for your enjoyment](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/docs/example-simple).  With SimpleJMX you use the `folderNames` annotation field to specify the folders:

```
@JmxResource(domainName = "j256.com", folderNames = { "counters" },
    beanName = "RuntimeCounter")
```

This generates the `ObjectName` of `"j256.com:00=counters,name=RuntimeCounter"`.

Comment: I noticed this page (http://mikescode.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/jmx-and-spring-is-magic/), which seems to use the "type" property to do something similar, although it doesn't show how it might show up in the JMX viewer.  Is there some place where this "subFolder" thing is documented?

Comment: I think the `"type"` is just a name.  It could be `t` or in my case is `00`.  As far as I can tell, the `00` is never used aside from its alphabetic order in the name @DavidM.Karr.

Comment: I don't know where it is documented.  I had to figure out the alphanumeric ordering way back when myself @DavidM.Karr.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the semantics of this syntax.  How would you add another folder underneath "subFolder" and "peer" folders to "subFolder" and "folder"?

Comment: So to add another folder you would just add a `,02=...` section to the name.  If you wanted the bean in the `folder` but _not_ the `subFolder` then you would remove the `,01=...` section from the name @DavidM.Karr.  This is going to become obvious once you use it.

Comment: I'm guessing that "02" would add a folder WITHIN "subFolder", but how would I have an additional folder within "folder" as a peer of "subFolder"?

Comment: The name would have `01=folder,02=subFolder2`.  If you want another folder below the domain then you should do `01=folder2` @DavidM.Karr.

Comment: I just noticed this article about "jmx namespaces": https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2008/09/jmx_namespaces.html .  This seems to provide a similar feature.

Comment: To get more than 10 folders at any one level, I assume that after "9" I would use "a", for instance?

Comment: I use `00=...` so that would be `10=...`.  `a` does come after `9` however so that would work too @DavidM.Karr.

Comment: The name of the keys in the ObjectName don't matter to VisualVM or JConsole.  You can use any key names.  They just create "folders" for each key in the object name.  Key names do have to be unique within a single ObjectName though.  For example, "foo.com:00=folder,name=someBean" will display the same as "foo.com:Type=folder,name=someBean".

Comment: Just so it's clear, if I'm mapping something like a package path, and I have a bunch of components like this, I can simply do: "00=pkgcmp1,01=pkgcmp2,02=pkgcmp3,03=pkgcmp4" where the package path is like "pkgcmp1.pkgcmp2.pkgcmp3.pkgcmp4.ComponentName"?  And I would use the same numbers for each different component, but different "pkcgmp?" values?

Comment: For the record, this strategy worked on the first try.  I just split into an array on "/" (that's my folder entry separator) and used a value of '"0" + ctr' (ctr from 0 to length - 1).  It just worked.

Comment: Despite the fact that this works, I really need to know: Where is this documented?  Does the JMX specification say, even ambiguously, that this should work?

Comment: Don't know if this is part of the JMX spec @DavidM.Karr.  To JMX the `ObjectName` is the `ObjectName`.  What you are talking about is how jconsole and VisualVM _visualize_ the `ObjectName`.  That is part of the specification of those programs, not JMX.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the order they appear in the string and nothing else. Therefore you can't use the `ObjectName(String, Hashtable)` constructor because the ordering is undefined.